# 2 functions doesn`t work together, but each function works by itself [unity]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm an english learner and I may have some mistakes, sorry about that.
I'm passing through unity tutorial and i want to realise an elevator.
[Unity Essentials](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/challenge-moving-sound?uv=2021.3&pathwayId=5f7bcab4edbc2a0023e9c38f&missionId=5f777d9bedbc2a001f6f5ec7&projectId=5faab859edbc2a00209536ce#63754547edbc2a3ca36ae31f)
But it doesn't work. I wrote 2 functions for move up and down.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Elevator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 positionChange;
    void Start()
    {

    }
    void Update()
    {
      elevator_up();
      elevator_down();
    }
    void elevator_up()
    {
            if (transform.position.y <= 3.81f) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++)
            {
                transform.localPosition += positionChange * Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }
        Debug.Log("first finish");

    }
    void elevator_down()
    {
        if (transform.position.y >= -0.03f)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++)
            {
                transform.localPosition -= positionChange *Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }
        Debug.Log("second finish");
    }
}
```

It works for each function, but when I try to combine these functions in Update method it doesn't work.
I have an assumption that each function interrupt another, but I'm not sure about it.
Help please! Why doesn't it work? How can I fix it?

I had tried realise this system by using for and while.
In the both ways it doesn't work. I also added Time.deltaTime (i assumed that my problem has problems with time)

Comment: you put both in Update() this will not work because both funcitons are running at the same time, you have to control your functions when the elevator reaches the the top it goes down, and when it reaches the bottom it goes up.

Comment: Put `elevator_down` at the bottom of `elevator_up`, and vice versa.

Comment: `elevator_up` moves the elevator up 150 times in one frame, then in the same frame `elevator_down` moves the elevator down 150 times.